# ng-click function parameters not making it to handler (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs, parameter-passing, angularjs-ng-click

This is the sample code I have:

```
<a ng-click="$parent.infoLinkClickHandler('hard-param', car.engineSize)">{{ car.engineSize }}</a></li>
```

And in the handler:

```
$scope.infoLinkClickHandler = function(param1, param2) {
// do something here
        };
```

param1, the hard-coded parameter is there

param2, is undefined

On the markup, {{ car.engineSize }} prints as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the scope inside the attribute ng-click is different to that inside the {{}}.

Is the HTML shown the exact HTML, or have you simplified it for the question?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is. Question is way over-simplified from the real situation. I'm using multiple directives within directives (google maps), and things got lost in all the scopes.